# iTextSharp Pdftable Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

I am facing issue while generating pdf from Windows form using iTextSharp dll. I am populating more than 70 records at a time in a dataset and I am binding same to new table(pdfptable) by looping. But it says Object reference not set to instance of object. when I reduced number of rows to 68 it works fine. After analysis I found that table is not able to split along the multiple pages.

I am using following piece of code. Please help

```
            float[] widths1 = new float[] { 1f, 2f,1f,1f,1f,1f,1f};

            PdfPTable grd = new PdfPTable(GrdAnoSecList.Columns.Count);
            grd.SetWidths(widths1);

            for (int i = 0; i < GrdAnoSecList.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                PdfPCell ph;
                if (Convert.ToString(GrdAnoSecList.Columns[i].HeaderText) == "Job Name")
                {
                    ph = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(GrdAnoSecList.Columns[i].HeaderText, grdfontHdr));
                    ph.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(240, 240, 240);
                    ph.BorderWidthTop = 0;
                    ph.BorderWidthRight = 0;
                    ph.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                     ph= new PdfPCell(new Phrase(GrdAnoSecList.Columns[i].HeaderText, grdfontHdr));
                     ph.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(240, 240, 240);
                     ph.BorderWidthTop = 0;
                     ph.BorderWidthRight = 0;
                     ph.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                     //ph.Width = 100f;
                }

                grd.AddCell(ph);
            }
            int ct = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GrdAnoSecList.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    ct++;
                    PdfPCell ph2;
                    if (Convert.ToString(cell.Value) == "Total")
                    {
                        ph2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell.Value.ToString(), grdfontHdr));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ph2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell.Value.ToString(), myfont));
                    }
                    if (cell.ValueType == typeof(decimal) || cell.ValueType == typeof(Int32))
                    {
                        ph2.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
                    }
                    else if (cell.ColumnIndex == 1 && Convert.ToString(cell.Value) != "Total")
                    {
                        ph2.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ph2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    }

                    grd.AddCell(ph2);

                }
            }

            PdfPCell cellAmountText1 = new PdfPCell(new PdfPTable(grd));
            cellAmountText1.Colspan = 6;
            table.AddCell(cellAmountText1);
```

Comment: Your question can't be answered by someone who doesn't know how many elements there are in `GrdAnoSecList.Columns.Count` and `row.Cells`. It's also strange that you have `cellAmountText1.Colspan = 6;` whereas you define 7 columns. Where is the 7th cell? There is no reason why, in a normal table, good code would work for 68 rows, but not for 70 rows. A table normally splits correctly when the end of a page is reached, but your code is very hard to read, and it's incomplete: we don't see how you're adding the table.

Comment: There are two tables. The second one is nested in first one. The first table(table) consist of 6 cells where as second table (grd) consist of 7 cells. The second one is dynamically generated and finally gets added to first one.